# Should I keep this API hash a secret?

Tags: hash, api

I am using a service called "Lootably", and in order to verify postback requests, they require you to verify using a SHA256 hash, like this:

`hash("sha256", userID . ip . revenue . currencyReward . "9Zu4zcAvkKFE789hgfejYJJKGHGGjhe879hejkHUIakHNMqHWEWRhiHJKqw886KEgwh")`

(This is an example, it isn't valid).

Would I keep the "`9Zu4zcAvkKFE789hgfejYJJKGHGGjhe879hejkHUIakHNMqHWEWRhiHJKqw886KEgwh`" a secret through an environment variable? Could somebody use this to make postback API requests?

Comment: Where do you get the salt from? Is everything else (user id, ip, revenue, currency reward) public info? Is your server used only by you?

Comment: Who would you need to keep the hash a secret from? I think this is missing some context.

Comment: No, the User ID and IP aren't secret.

Comment: The answer to this is clearly provided in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the secrecy of your userid and ip are low.
The revenue and currentcy reward values are probably slightly higher, but still potentially guessable.

The point of hashing all of those with the random secret is to increase the security of the group.   If you then leak that salt, you have then reduced the security level back to those four potentially visible values.

Also note that environment variables are visible other user on the same system.  If there are other users, you may want to consider another way to transport it.

Comment: userID and IP are protected data in many data protection legislation. So, those would need to be kept secret.

Comment: While that's true, they leak very easily, and out of all the protected data, userid has the lowest protection.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in the [repository](https://github.com/lootably/lootably-postback-hash), the value that you posted here (9Zu4zcAvk...) should be secret. It seems to exist "to ensure the postback is actually being sent by Lootably". It's indeed a good idea to store the secret in a key vault, and to pass it as an environment variable during deployment.

From what I understand, Lootably does a postback to your server with the user data (`userID, ip, revenue, currencyReward`), together with a `hash = postback-hash(userdata, secret)`. You can verify that this came from Lootably by comparing this hash with one you generate yourself with `hash_local = postback-hash(userdata, secret)`.